# If my apple developer account is expired, is installed application still running?

Tags: ios

I have an Apple Developer Account, and an app on the App Store.

Can my users who have already downloaded my app run it even after my developer account expires?

Has anyone tested this?

Comment: of cause yes. user won't lost their app just because you did not pay $99 this year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** your users will still be able to use the app. However, the app will be removed from the App Store and no new users will be able to download it until you renew your membership.